# Trouble with while loop and end = ' '

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm writing a program in which a range of numbers prints on one line. However my code:

```
while True:
    user = int(input('Enter'))
    if user > 0 :
        for x in range (0,user +1):
            print(x,end=' ')
```

Has the following output:

```
Enter9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Enter
```

Why does enter print on the same line? How do I change this?

Comment: Because, you used `end=''`, so at the end of your `while` block, just put a `print()` which will print a newline

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. I see `Enter9` but after the `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 `, `Enter` appears on a newline.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
while True:
    user = int(input('Enter'))
    if user > 0 :
        for x in range (0,user +1):
            print(x,end=' ')
        print()
```

You have to add just one `print()` statement after `for` loop. This makes sure that a line break is added after the elements in the range sequence is printed out.

Answer (score 1):

Your print command does not end with a new line. Add:

```
print()
```

after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code prints "Enter" on the same line because you set the "end" parameter of `print` to `' '`. Therefore, when you print "Enter" you begin in the same line and not in a new one. The default value of "end" is `\n` meaning that after the print statement it will print a new line.

I'd suggest you to add `\n` before you print "Enter". This will fix your problem and will be easier to read. Try to change your code to this:

```
while True:
    user = int(input('\nEnter: '))
    if user > 0 :
        for x in range (0,user +1):
            print(x,end=' ')
```

And you'll see results similar to this:

```
Enter: 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Enter: 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Enter: 4 
0 1 2 3 4
Enter: 1 
0 1
```